# How to copy PVC between different storage classes?

Tags: kubernetes

I know about snapshots and tested volume cloning. And it works, when storage class is the same.

But what if I have two storage classes: one for fast ssd and second for cold storage hdd over network and I want periodically make backup to cold storage? How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloning is supported with a different Storage Class
You need to use CSI Provisioning and apply something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
    name: clone-of-pvc-1
    namespace: myns
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: cloning
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  dataSource:
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    name: pvc-1
```

[Full documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-pvc-datasource/#provisioning)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a thing Kubernetes supports since it would be entirely up to your underlying storage. The simple version would be a pod that mounts both and runs `rsync` I guess?

Comment: Is this a design decision? Could you add some source for this information? I found lot's of ways, but nothing that is not weird workaround.

Comment: Snapshots are the way to copy from one CSI volume to a new instance (make snapshot, make a new PV seeded from that snapshot) but CSI has 0 provisions for cross-provider actions of any kind. In the case of "make volume from snapshot" that's because it's usually a native operation in the backend and you can't, say, create an  EBS volume from a ZFS snapshot or vice versa. The underlying systems have no connection and Kubernetes is not a file management abstraction layer.

Comment: OK, I think I get it. Every CSI driver is separate universe that operates it's PVs, snapshots separately. Despite the fact, that all of them provides conscience volume interface, k8s cannot use it to migrate abstracted volume between CSIs. Right?

Comment: Correct, mostly. You could technically write two CSI plugins that just agree to coordinate their snapshot naming scheme or something but no such plugins exist and they wouldn't make much sense since the underlying issue isn't CSI, it's that "snapshot -> new volume" means something totally different in most storage systems.